# No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'FilterDescriptor'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have Visual Studio 2022 with a .NET 7 API project in it. I have been building out a set of models and having EntityFramwork build the database in Microsoft Sql Server. That has been going great. Today I added a .NET 7 Web App (MVC) to the solution and now Add-Migration throws this error. This doesn't make sense to me because I don't have a 'FilterDescriptor' class or FilterDescriptor method anywhere in my project. This only started after adding the MVC project. I can remove the MCV project and it works again without a problem. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'FilterDescriptor'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
> Cannot bind 'filter', 'filterScope' in 'FilterDescriptor(IFilterMetadata filter, int filterScope)'
> Note that only mapped properties can be bound to constructor parameters. Navigations to related entities, including references to owned types, cannot be bound.

API.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Models\ApplicationUser.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Next" Version="4.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="7.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

MVC.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

```
public class BudgetingAPIDbContext : DbContext
    {
        //public readonly string _connectionString;
        public DbSet<BudgetModel> budgetModels { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<CategoryModel> categoryModels { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<ExpenseModel> expenseModels { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<IncomeModel> incomeModels { get; set; } = null;
        public DbSet<PaymentPlanModel> paymentPlanModels { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<RegisterViewModel> registerViewModels { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<TransactionModel> transactions { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<UserModel> userModels { get; set; } = null;
        public DbSet<AuthController> authControllers { get; set; } = null;

        public BudgetingAPIDbContext(DbContextOptions<BudgetingAPIDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
```

```
public class BudgetModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Name can only contain letters.")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserModel> UserModels { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Description can only contain letters.")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<IncomeModel>? Incomes { get; set; }
    public List<ExpenseModel>? Expenses { get; set; }
    public List<TransactionModel>? Transactions { get; set; }
    public PaymentPlanModel PaymentPlan { get; set; }

    public BudgetModel()
    {

    }

    public BudgetModel(int id,
                       string name,
                       string description,
                       DateTime startDate,
                       DateTime endDate,
                       DateTime createdDate,
                       DateTime modifiedDate,
                       int createdBy,
                       int modifiedBy,
                       bool isActive,
                       PaymentPlanModel paymentPlan,
                       List<UserModel> userModels)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        CreatedDate = createdDate;
        ModifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        CreatedBy = createdBy;
        ModifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        IsActive = isActive;
        PaymentPlan = paymentPlan;
        UserModels = userModels;
    }

    public BudgetModel(UserModel user, string name, string description, PaymentPlanModel paymentPlan)
    {
        List<UserModel> UserModels = new List<UserModel>();
        UserModels.Add(user);
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        PaymentPlan = paymentPlan;
        StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        CreatedBy = user.Id;
        ModifiedBy = user.Id;
        IsActive = true;
    }
}

public class CategoryModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Name can only contain letters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public CategoryModel()
    {
        // default constructor
    }

    public CategoryModel(string name, string type, bool isDefault, int? userId)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Default = isDefault;
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public CategoryModel(int id, string name, string type, bool isDefault, int? userId)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Default = isDefault;
        UserId = userId;
    }

}
public class ExpenseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Name can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Description can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Amount must be a number with up to two decimal places.")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    public ExpenseType Type { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Address can only contain letters.")]
    public string Address { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "City can only contain letters.")]
    public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "State can only contain letters.")]
    public string State { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Zip must be a 5-digit number.")]
    public string Zip { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Country can only contain letters.")]
    public string Country { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Phone]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(1-)?\d{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Phone number must be a valid 10-digit phone number.")]
    public string? Phone { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string? Email { get; set; }

    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Website must be a valid URL.")]
    public string? Website { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BudgetModel")]
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public BudgetModel? BudgetModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public UserModel? Creator { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserModel? User { get; set; }


    public ExpenseModel()
    {

    }

    public ExpenseModel(int id,
                        int budgetId,
                        string name,
                        string description,
                        decimal amount,
                        DateTime date,
                        CategoryModel category,
                        ExpenseType type,
                        string _address,
                        string _city,
                        string _state,
                        string _zip,
                        string _phone,
                        string _email,
                        string _website)
    {
        Id = id;
        BudgetId = budgetId;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Amount = amount;
        Date = date;
        Category = category;
        Type = type;
        Address = _address;
        City = _city;
        State = _state;
        Zip = _zip;
        Phone = _phone;
        Email = _email;
        Website = _website;
    }

    public enum ExpenseType
    {
        Bill,
        Loan,
        Other
    }
}
public class IncomeModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Name can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Description can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Amount must be a number with up to two decimal places.")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BudgetModel")]
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public BudgetModel? BudgetModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public UserModel? Creator { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserModel? User { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "FrequencyInt must be a positive integer.")]
    public int FrequencyInt { get; set; }

    public string? FrequencyString { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Source can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string? Source { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Account can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.")]
    public string? Account { get; set; }

    public bool IsRecurring { get; set; }


    public IncomeModel()
    {

    }

    public IncomeModel(string _Name, string _Description, decimal _amount, DateTime _startTime, int _createdBy)
    {
        Name = _Name;
        Description = _Description;
        Amount = _amount;
        StartDate = _startTime;
        EndDate = _startTime;
        CreatedBy = _createdBy;
    }

    public IncomeModel(int _id,
                       string _Name,
                       string _Description,
                       decimal _amount,
                       DateTime _startTime,
                       DateTime _endTime,
                       int _createdBy,
                       int _modifiedBy,
                       DateTime _createdDate,
                       DateTime _modifiedDate,
                       bool _isActive,
                       int? _CategoryId,
                       string _Source,
                       string _Account,
                       bool _IsRecurring)
    {
        Id = _id;
        Name = _Name;
        Description = _Description;
        Amount = _amount;
        StartDate = _startTime;
        EndDate = _endTime;
        CreatedBy = _createdBy;
        ModifiedBy = _modifiedBy;
        CreatedDate = _createdDate;
        ModifiedDate = _modifiedDate;
        IsActive = _isActive;
        CategoryId = _CategoryId;
        Source = _Source;
        Account = _Account;
        IsRecurring = _IsRecurring;
    }
}
    public class InviteToBudgetModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
        public int Invitor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string InviteeEmail { get; set; } = null!;
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("BudgetModel")]
        public int? BudgetId { get; set; }
        public BudgetModel? BudgetModel { get; set; }



        public InviteToBudgetModel(BudgetModel budgetModel, UserModel userModel, string inviteeEmail)
        {
            Invitor = userModel.Id;
            InviteeEmail = inviteeEmail;
            BudgetId = budgetModel.Id;
        }
    }
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 8 characters, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.")]

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]

        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
public class TransactionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Name can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Description can only contain letters, numbers, and spaces.")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Amount must be a number with up to two decimal places.")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BudgetModel")]
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public BudgetModel? BudgetModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public UserModel? Creator { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModel")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserModel? User { get; set; }

    public CategoryModel? Category { get; set; }

    public TransactionModel(string name, string description, decimal amount, DateTime date, int budgetId, int userId)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Amount = amount;
        Date = date;
        BudgetId = budgetId;
        UserId = userId;
    }

}
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "UserName can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "First Name can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Last Name can only contain letters and spaces.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 8 characters, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.")]
    public string? Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public bool isAdmin { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "PIN must be a 4-digit number.")]
    public string Pin { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Security Question can only contain letters.")]
    public string SecurityQestion { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Security Answer can only contain letters.")]
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Address can only contain letters.")]
    public string Address { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "City can only contain letters.")]
    public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "State can only contain letters.")]
    public string State { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Zip must be a 5-digit number.")]
    public string Zip { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Country can only contain letters.")]
    public string Country { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public bool MFA { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "MFA Key can only contain letters and numbers.")]
    public string MFAKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public UserModel()
    {

    }
    public UserModel(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string passwordHash)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;

    }

    public UserModel(int id,
                     string firstName,
                     string lastName,
                     string email,
                     string passwordHash,
                     DateTime createdDate,
                     DateTime modifiedDate,
                     bool isAdmin,
                     bool isActive,
                     string pin,
                     string securityQestion,
                     string securityAnswer,
                     string phone,
                     string address,
                     string city,
                     string state,
                     string zip,
                     string country)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Email = email;
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        CreatedDate = createdDate;
        ModifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        Pin = pin;
        SecurityQestion = securityQestion;
        SecurityAnswer = securityAnswer;
        Phone = phone;
        Address = address;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Zip = zip;
        Country = country;
    }



}
```

Comment: share your entity classes and db context

Comment: I added the DbContext. For the rest it may be easier to share the GitHub. [link](https://github.com/josephcambron/FamilyBudgetAPIWAuth)

Comment: Share your entity classes too please

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't have Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration Nuget Package installed and dependency infection for the configuration. I'm not sure why it didn't error until I added a second project.